# Split an int array of non-contiguous values into several contiguous int arrays

Tags: java

```
int[] big = {1,2,3,5,11,12,13,25,26};
```

doSomething to make the contiguous elements together
how to split 'big' into this:

```
{{1,2,3},{5},{11,12,13},{25,26}}
```

I've started with this code:

```
public List<Integer> getR(){
    Integer[] big = {1,2,3,5,11,12,13,25,26};
    List<Integer> a = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    for(int i=0;i<big.length;i++){
        if(big[i]==big[i+1]-1){
            continue;
        }else{
            //...
        }
        //...
    }
    //...
}
```

Comment: Is the big array always in sorted order?

Comment: yes, it always is in sorted order. :-)

Comment: the only criteria is to make splited them into contiguous elements.:-)

Comment: There must be more criterions than that, otherwise you don't have to do anything. Is there a minimum number of splits you need, or a maximum size per chunk?

Comment: there is a wsdl interface. it needs me to provide the min and max int as parameters. but the int numbers I have are not contiguous. then I need to split the numbers and use the wsdl interface sevral times.

Comment: Why would you not mention that from the beginning?

Comment: @jahroy because having the WSDL does not add any value to the question. If a question is too difficult to understand, there is a close option for that. No reason to tell people this or that about homework as though it is a pejorative.

Comment: @TimBender - Agreed that the WSDL part doesn't matter... But if there are additional requirements to the question, they should be mentioned.  I was referring to the part where she said: "_it needs me to provide the min and max int as parameters_".  To be honest, I don't understand what she means, but it seems like it's an important part of the question.  I don't feel that I have harassed anybody here, but I will take your words into consideration in the future regarding potential homework questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You resulting array is a two-dimensional array and something as follows is allowed in Java.

```
int[][] split = new int[4][]; 
split[0] = new int[3];
split[1] = new int[1];
split[1] = new int[3];
split[1] = new int[2];
//note: you can use variables instead integer values (like 4, 3, 2, ...) here
```

You can utilize that information to form the new array.

---

**Update**

```
List<List<Integer>> result = new ArrayList<List<Integer>>();
List<Integer> curr = null;
for (int i = 0; i < big.length; i++) {
    if(i == 0 || (big[i] != big[i-1]+1)) { 
        //if the current element is the first element or doesn't satisfy the condition
        curr = new ArrayList<Integer>(); //create a new list and set it to curr
        result.add(curr); //add the newly created list to the result list
    }
    curr.add(big[i]); //add current element to the curr list
}
```

Comment: I need it like this: [code]    public List<Integer> getR(){
 Integer[] big = {1,2,3,5,11,12,13,25,26};
 List<Integer> a = new ArrayList<Integer>();
 for(int i=0;i<big.length;i++){
     if(big[i]==big[i+1]-1){
  continue;
     }else{

Comment: You should post your code on the question itself.

Comment: YES! YES!! YES!!! Thank you, Bhesh. You are my super hero!!!! :D :D This is exactly what I want!!!! How great this is!!!! WA HAHAHA!!! and YAHOOOOOOOOOOO! Wish you have a very good day!!!! Thank you SOOOOOOOO much!!!:D :D :D

Answer (score 8):

I can give you the pseudo code.

1. Iterate over the array.
2. add first element to another array and advance one step.
3. see if the current element is previous number+1
4. if it is, add to the second array
5. else, create a new array and add to it.
6. repeat steps 3 though 5 till you've reached the end.

Now you have the arrays. If it everything was already contiguous, you'll essentially have created a copy for the first array.

Comment: +1 for giving pseudo code and not providing a copy/paste solution

Comment: Thank you, Vaishak. I appreciate that. And it would be really grateful if I could have the Java code about this. Thanks a lot. :-)

Comment: This sounds like do my homework... :S

Comment: @Nancy - For questions like this (where the OP has shown no effort), it's better **not** to provide actual code.  You are clearly a student who wants somebody to do your homework.  That's not the point of this website.

Comment: @jahroy I think that is an unfair assumption. The OP could be a student or perhaps a non-CS person trying to do something "trivial" in a business app.

Comment: @TimBender - Fair enough.  However, I would argue that this question is perfect for either of those cases.

Comment: Btw -1 because the pseudo code does not address how to size the individual resultant arrays.

Comment: @TimBender even if so, "I want this to transform into this, give me the code" is still not the purpose of the website, is it? Vaishak's pseudo code is perfect in the current scenario. If the OP cannot handle an iteration over an array he probably shouldn't be doing anything on any app, before he/she gets the basic knowledge.

Comment: @Nikola If you personally feel that a question is not of high quality, then the appropriate response is to vote to close, not to harass people about whether or not it is homework. I also don't think there is anything wrong with pseudo-code as a solution. Just that this pseudo-code is wrong, that is why I downvoted.

Comment: @TimBender to handle the size issue, one could just do away with the array while iterating and put everything into separate collections (Lists?) then do a conversions (use toArray()).

Did not add those specifics because I was just giving the pseudo-code.

Comment: @VaishakSuresh actually it would be better to iterate the original array whilst keeping track of the `start` of a contiguous sequence. Then when the `end` of the sequence is found, one could simply use `System.arrayCopy` with the appropriate indices. That would be a much cleaner solution than switching to a `List`.

Comment: @TimBender Agreed! Precisely why I did not give the specifics in the pseudo-code. There are many ways to do it and each can be better than the previous one but nonetheless, point taken.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a method to sort your array by contiguous sizes, and a main method to test it:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] big = {1,2,3,5,11,12,13,25,26};
    try {
        System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(splitContiguous(big, 3, 1, 3, 2)));
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
public static int[][] splitContiguous(int[] original, int... ranges) throws Exception {
    if (original.length == 0 || ranges.length == 0 || ranges.length > original.length) {
        throw new Exception("TODO handle some mess...");
    }
    int[][] result = new int[ranges.length][];
    int rangesIndex = 0;
    int index = 0;
    for (int range: ranges) {
        result[rangesIndex] = new int[range];
        for (int i = 0; i < range; i++) {
            result[rangesIndex][i] = original[index];
            index++;
        }
        rangesIndex++;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Output:

```
[[1, 2, 3], [5], [11, 12, 13], [25, 26]]
```

Comment: Good job on the solution, but [imo] it should not be posted, as this is obviously a homework and there is not effort given by the OP.

Comment: @Nikola thanks, and you're right. But I was bored out of my brains :D Anyhow, I'm off to bed now.

Comment: Thanks, Mena. This absolutely can solve my proble. :-) Wish you have a great day!!

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;


public class testSth {

    public List<List<Integer>> getR(){
    Integer[] big = {1,2,3,5,11,12,13,25,26};
    List<Integer> a = Arrays.asList(big);
    List<List<Integer>> all = new ArrayList<List<Integer>>();

    for(int i=0;i<a.size();i++){
        List<Integer> b = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        if(a.get(i)==a.get(i+1)-1){
        b.add(a.get(i));
        }else{
        b.add(a.get(i));
        all.add(b);
        }
    }
    return all;
    }
}
```

Comment: It's actually pretty simple using the `List`s. Check out the update in my answer. The `ArrayList` here takes care of stuffs, behind the scene, that we would have to do manually if we were using arrays only, because arrays cannot grow/shrink once created.

Answer (score 0):

there is another answer base on what Mena's answer

```
int[] flag=new int[big.length];
int j=0;
flag[0]=0;
for(int i=1;i<big.length;i++){
if(!big[i-1]+1==big[i]) j++;
flag[i]=j;
}
```

the output would be: 0 0 0 1 2 2 2 3 3, than you can see it also can work out a way to solve this